# there is a face detection API for WinRT?

Tags: winapi, windows-8, windows-runtime, face-detection

I see statements on the web about Windows 8 supporting face detection. Is this face detection or face recognition or both? (I don't care so much about recognition.) Is it in an API available inside a WinRT application and/or .Net? Where's the documentation for this API? (MSDN and Google both give me links to Windows Phone 7 stuff.)

Comment: Well, now that you ask, it appears that a web search of '"windows 8" "face detection"' brings up a bunch of rumor sites but nothing substantive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in API for this in WinRT.  You will have to use a web service for this functionality or build one yourself.